# Disable Push notifications programmatically on Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification

How to disable Push notifications programmatically on Flutter without no need to go to Settings -> Push Notifications of the app?

This package [notification_permissions](https://pub.dev/packages/notification_permissions) only get and request NotificationPermissions.

And [FirebaseMessaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) can't disable Push notifications programmatically as well.

Right now I use the package [app_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) which opens the Settings of the app.

In the video I do it manually but I want to do it programmatically.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690253/how-to-disable-cloud-messaging-per-device-user-in-flutter

Comment: Kaushik Chandru thanks, 
I understand that I can control sending Push notifications with boolean flag on server. But it will not turn off in phone settings allowing push notifications.

Comment: Oh got it. No i dont think its possible without taking the user to the settings page. Sorry if i am wrong. You can probably make the usera subscribe and unsubscribe to topics. And you can push notifications to that specific topic.

Comment: Sure, no prob. Thanks for your help Kaushik Chandru. Yep, I can do like that but it takes more effort to implement.

Comment: I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345823/ios-how-to-disable-push-notification-at-logout that maybe on iOS I can use `UIApplication.shared.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()` but some dart/flutter library has to implement it.

Comment: Your app doesn't need to ask for "push notifications" permission. It needs to ask for permission to display notifications. This display permission applies to both local and remote (push) notifications.  Once you have asked for notification display permission you cannot modify the users selection in the app.  Only the user can change them in settings. You can use the app settings url to open your apps settings page directly.

Answer (score 8):

Use [deleteToken](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/deleteToken.html) which invalidates the current token and [getToken](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/getToken.html) again to get a new one when enabling.

> Removes access to an FCM token previously authorized.
> Messages sent by the server to this token will fail.